# .split python word count

Tags: python, string

I need to count the words in a sentence. For example, "I walk my dog." Would be 4 words, but "I walk my 3 dogs" would only be 4 words because numbers are not words. The code can only count alphabetic words. I understand how to count words by simply using the following:

```
len(string.split)
```

but this doesn't account for numbers. Is there a simply way (for a beginner) to account for numbers, symbols, etc? thank you.

Comment: What about "I walk my Beagle-Harrier"?  Is that a possible sentence of four words?  (I ask because it will break some `isalpha()` approaches.)

Comment: I would submit that numbers in a sentence *are* words.

Comment: What if I spelled `4` as `four` instead? The meaning of the sentence has not changed! `4` is a word too in your sentence.

Answer (score 4):

```
totalWords = sum(1 for word in line.split() if word.isalpha())
```

You can use `split` function on the line to split it based on spaces. And then check if each word has only alphabets using `isalpha` function. If it is true, then include 1. Sum all of them at the end.

Comment: if there anyway of doing this without using .isalpha that you can think of? Somehow make a list of your string or something?

Comment: @jerry2144 Do you consider punctutation marks as well as the word separators?

Comment: `if not word.isdigit()` would allow `"don't"` and `'back-to-back'` to be counted as words.  Of course, `'3rd'` and `'3.145'` would count as words.  Perhaps `if not word[0].isdigit()` would be better.  But you would still have a problem with `"'3"` in `"'3 cats are missing,' she said."`  Least problematic would be `if any(c.isalpha() for c in word)`.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski Yup. I thought of all the cases for which this could fail. But its not very clear what does he exactly expect. :(

Answer (score 2):

Here's another option:

```
import re

lines = [
    'I walk by dog',
    'I walk my 3 dogs',
    'I walk my Beagle-Harrier' # DSM's example
]

for line in lines:
    words = re.findall('[a-z-]+', line, flags=re.I)
    print line, '->', len(words), words

# I walk by dog -> 4 ['I', 'walk', 'by', 'dog']
# I walk my 3 dogs -> 4 ['I', 'walk', 'my', 'dogs']
# I walk my Beagle-Harrier -> 4 ['I', 'walk', 'my', 'Beagle-Harrier']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.isalpha()` on strings.

```
len([word for word in sentence.split() if word.isalpha()])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use `.isalpha`

```
sum(not word.isdigit() for word in line.split())
```

This will return `True` for each word that is not a number, and `False` for each word that is a number.  This code takes advantage of the fact that in python, `True == 1` and `False == 0`, so you will get the number of non-number words.

---

If you are uncomfortable with using the `int`-ness of `bool`s, you can make it explicit to the reader of your code by adding the `int` function (this is 100% not needed, but can make the code clearer if you like it that way)

```
sum(int(not word.isdigit()) for word in line.split())
```

Comment: If your requirements are more than simply not numbers, let me know and I can modify this to your needs.  I am basing this code on your example.  What if you had something like "I <3 U"?  "<3" is not counted as a digit.

Answer (score 0):

Since, due to comments it looks like he wants something that doesn't use .isalpha, we could run this in a try/except.

```
count = 0
for word in line.split():
    try:
        int(word)
    except ValueError:
        count += 1
```

I know it's not pretty, but it handles it correctly.

Comment: Or perhaps `float(word)` to get rid of floating points as well.  Your try-except has the similar behavior to just checking `not word.isdigit()`.

Comment: I assumed that since the op didn't want .isalpha, that he wouldn't want any of he others of that style.